# pdfposter: crop / tile / posterize long PDF to multi pages from Safari Export as PDF

Tags: pdf, safari, crop

When I save a webpage with *Safari's > File > Export as PDF...*
Safari renders a long PDF in several (long) pages.

Here a screenshot of Preview's Crop Inspector
The [200 inch](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/When-200-inch-page-limit-broken-q36927.aspx) height appears to be a distiller’s limit for PostScript, based on the Windows printer driver limitation.

[image]

Before saving I set *Safari > Develop > Show Responsive Design Mode*
for my iPad mini with a resolution of 768 x 1024 (portrait)
The beauty of this feature (unlike *File > Print*) is that it can be used with Safari in *Responsive Design Mode*, so an exact snapshot of the webpage (responsive layout, images and even dark modes) gets exported to PDF, without any print margins and such.

--> Now I want to cut / tile / crop / posterize / de-impose (or whatever one should call it) these [200 inch or 14400 pt long] long pages into more manageable page sizes.
So with *Responsive Design Mode* set to iPad mini (768 x 1024) I would like to cut to the same dimensions; a mediabox / cropbox of 768pt x 1024pt

I tried already various command line tools like [BRISS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/), [PDFTILECUT](https://github.com/oxplot/pdftilecut), [PLAKATIV](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/plakativ), [MUPDF](https://www.mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-poster.html) ecc.

Some libraries like the Python binding [PYMUPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-general.html#how-to-split-single-pages) seem to convert the PDF to an image first to get it cut, thus loosing all the hyperlinks = NO go

Until now I get a decent result with [PDFPOSTER](https://pdfposter.readthedocs.io/) using following command line; I have set the height of the `--poster-size` BOX to something really long 100000pt

```
pdfposter \ 
-v \
-m 768x1024pt \
-p 768x1000000pt \
Safari-Export-as-PDF-IN.pdf \
Safari-Export-as-PDF-OUT.pdf
```

That works for all the pages, one after the other, but **I can’t find a solution to set the Y coordinates of the first page to 0**
The pages always seem to start from the bottom of the poster size, leaving space at the top..

Example PDF: >>> [download here](http://www.rrose.it/uploads/Safari-Export-as-PDF-IN.pdf) <<<

```
---------          =========
|       |          | xxxxx |
=========          | xxxxx |
| xxxxx |          | xxxxx |
---------          ---------
| xxxxx |          | xxxxx |
| xxxxx |    ->    | xxxxx |
| xxxxx |          | xxxxx |
---------          ---------
| xxxxx |          | xxxxx |
| xxxxx |          =========
| xxxxx |          |       |
=========          ---------
```

Comment: Yeah initially I could not even try out pdfposter, because the PDF saved with Safari's > Export as PDF seemed corrupt, probably because of malformatted HTML? I tried with a very simple HTML page and did not get the errors. I run the PDF from example link through an online PDF repair tool. This was the error pdfposter gave me: `pdfposter: error: The input-file is either currupt or no PDF at all: Invalid Elementary Object starting with b'b' @7: b'3\n%\xc4\xe5\xf2\xe5\xeb\xa7\xf3\xa0\xd0\xc4\xc6\n3 0 obj\n<< /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 42988 >>\nstream\nx\x01\xec\xbd{\x93$Iu'`

Comment: Your first upload lost all links and even color space. Second upload,.. did you just use > File > Print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK with a lot of testing I found out something: **PDFPOSTER does not like PDF's generated from HTML**

I first made a 100x200px box in Illustrator and exported that to a PDF.

than run:

```
pdfposter -m 100x80pt -p 100x99999pt in-100x200.pdf out-100x200.pdf
```

This gives me a very nice result, the first page has a Crop Box of 100x40px and a Media Box of 100x80px, the rest of the pages Crop & Media Boxes of 100x80px

Than I made a very very basic HTML (left even out the doctype)

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:white;margin:0;padding:0">
<div style="background-color:gold;width:100%;height:1500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and run:

```
pdfposter -m 767x1024pt -p 767x99999pt cleanHTML-IN.pdf cleanHTML-OUT.pdf
```

And get the first page with a white margin in the top, like in my initial problem.
So this is actually the Crop Box which does not seem to be set when using a PDF generated from HTML?

> **UPDATE**:
> Thanks to PDFPOSTER I have found my way to [PYPDF](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf).
> Basically you define:
> `reader = PdfReader('in.pdf')`
> `writer = PdfWriter()`
> I than loop over the pages `page_x = reader.pages[i]` from the input file, set mediaboxes for each "new" page (like photocopying) and append it to the writer `writer.add_page(page_x)`
> Finally write out with `writer.write()`
> Regarding corrupt PDF files, [PIKEPDF](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf) a Python wrapper around [QPDF](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) features automatic repairs just by opening and saving the file.

```
# pikepdf / pikepdf: 
# https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf
# https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
# 
# py-pdf / pypdf: 
# https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf
# https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

import pikepdf, os, math
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

# define, could become arguments
pagecut_h  = 1024
inputfile  = 'in.pdf'
outputfile = 'out.pdf'

# repair with PikePDF
print("repairing {0} .....".format(inputfile))
pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open(inputfile)
pdf.save(inputfile + '.tmp')
pdf.close()
os.unlink(inputfile)
os.rename(inputfile + '.tmp', inputfile)

reader = PdfReader(inputfile)
writer = PdfWriter()

pages_n = len(reader.pages)
print('reading ..... {} input pages'
    .format(pages_n))

for i in range(pages_n):
    
    page   = reader.pages[i]
    page_w = page.mediabox.width
    page_h = page.mediabox.height
    
    print('input page {}/{} [w:{}, h:{}]'
        .format(i + 1, pages_n, page_w, page_h))
    
    if (page_h <= pagecut_h):
        print('> input page height is smaller than the cut height')
        print('appending original input page [w:{}, h:{}]'
            .format(page_w, page_h))
        writer.add_page(page)
    else:
        pagesfull_n = math.floor(page_h / pagecut_h)
        print('calculating .......... {} output pages'
            .format(pagesfull_n + 1))
        
        # first FULL page
        page.mediabox.left   = 0
        page.mediabox.right  = page_w
        page.mediabox.top    = page_h
        page.mediabox.bottom = page_h - pagecut_h
        print('appending output page 1/{} [w:{}, h:{}]'.
            format((pagesfull_n + 1), page_w, pagecut_h))
        writer.add_page(page)
        
        # other FULL pages
        for j in range(pagesfull_n - 1):
            page.mediabox.top    -= pagecut_h
            page.mediabox.bottom -= pagecut_h
            print('appending output page {}/{} [w:{}, h:{}]'
                .format((j + 2), (pagesfull_n + 1), page_w, pagecut_h))
            writer.add_page(page)
        
        # LAST (not full) page
        pagelast_h  = (page_h - (pagecut_h * pagesfull_n))
        page.mediabox.top    = pagelast_h
        page.mediabox.bottom = 0
        print('appending last output page {}/{} [w:{}, h:{}]'
            .format((pagesfull_n + 1), (pagesfull_n + 1), page_w, pagelast_h))
        writer.add_page(page)
    
with open(outputfile, 'wb') as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```